# map over nested array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display the values of the following data which is received when i make fetch request:

data: Array

```
0: Object
  title: "html"
  description: Array
  name: "xyz"
  class: "c"

1: Object
  title: "html1"
  description: Array
  name: "xyz1"
  class: "c1"
```

I have tried following code:

```
<div>
  {
    data.map((item, index) => {
      <h1 key={index}>{item.title}/</h1>
      { item.description.map((c, i) =>
        <div>
          <h3 key={i}>{c.name} {c.class}</h3>
        </div>
      )}
    })
  }
</div>
```

The above code displays only the title value. It's not displaying name and class value. Please help me.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Your data structure says that description is an array, not an object. Can you please share the data structure as it appears on your console?

Comment: I'm getting "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" warning

Comment: The `key` prop should be defined on the`div` not on `h3` when you map `item.description`.

Comment: It's very hard to make out what the data's actual structure is. It looks like `name` and `class` are elements of the main object, not the `description` array. Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))` and post what it shows.

Comment: I figured it out using the output of " console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)) ". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You were not returning anything to your `data.map`

```
{data.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h1 key={index}>{item.title}/</h1>
                  {item.description.map((c, i) => (
                    <div>
                      <h3 key={i}>
                        {c.name} {c.class1}
                      </h3>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

Answer (score -1):

If `description` is an object then you don't need to map over description again
this alone should do

```js
   <div>
   {
   data.map((item, index) => {

        <h1 key={index}>{item.title}/</h1>
        <div>
            <h3>{item.description.name} {item.description.class}</h3>
        </div>
  })
}
</div>
```